# tabulararray: What do negative coefficients for the extendable column mean?

Tags: tabulararray

When using the X column type in [tabulararray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en), what do negative coefficients mean?

It looks like it just fits columns with negative coefficients to the size of the contents, but then why is there a difference between -1 and -10 in the following example?:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-1]|X[1]|}
\hline
Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-1]|X[1]|}
\hline
Alpha & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-10]|X[1]|}
\hline
Alpha & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I believe negative numbers mean "at most". So `X[-10]` tries to adapt to its content but will be at most 10 times wider than `X[1]`. This seems clear in your second example: the column tries to adapt to the width of its content but can be at most as wide as the following column, hence the overfull box.

Comment: As prof. van Duck explains at p. 69 [here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-1/tb136duck-tabularray.pdf) "`X` columns with negative coefficients are also possible. In this case, the columns have their “natural width”, but are limited to the width of a corresponding `X` column with a positive coefficient. For instance, `X[-1]` is like an `l` column but if its width is greater than what an `X[1]` column would have had, then it is adapted to the `X[1]` column width."

Comment: Yes, I figured it out eventually. But thank you for that lovely document. It looks like a nice and useful read! :)

Comment: @KIAaze Pay attention that `tabularray` is very slow. If you have a lot of tables, avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after looking at the documentation of the [tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package, *section 2.3 tabu X columns – Mastering horizontal space*...

Since the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) documentation mentions it in *section 1.6 Column types*, I assumed it work the same way, which it looks like it does.

> Negative width coefficients can be given to X columns:
>
> ex: `X[-2.5]X[1] or X[-2.5]X or X[-5]X[2]`
>
> In this case, the first X column will be at most two and a half wider
> than the second one, and if the *natural width* of the first X column
> is finally less than 2.5 × (the width of the second column) then it
> will be narrowed down to this natural width.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-1]|X[1]|}
\hline
-1 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-2]|X[1]|}
\hline
-2 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-4]|X[1]|}
\hline
-4 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-5]|X[1]|}
\hline
-5 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-6]|X[1]|}
\hline
-6 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-7]|X[1]|}
\hline
-7 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\begin{tblr}{|X[2]|X[3]|X[-8]|X[1]|}
\hline
-8 & Beta & GammaGammaGammaGamma & Delta \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]